Indy Sockets 10.6.3.5 - IdRegister.pas(215): E2225 Never-build package 'IndyProtocols230' must be recompiled
I reinstalled Delphi 10 due to a persistent IDE error on start. After installing Delphi, I installed Indy 10 to this new install. I downloaded 10.6.3.5 from github, then deleted a previous install folder then created a new folder. To that, I then extracted the new download. I opened Delphi 10 to make sure Indy was not shown in the IDE components list - It was so I removed those entries then closed it. I then ran Lib\Clean_Seattle.cmd to remove any lingering files.
I successfully built System, built then installed Core, then tried building Protocols but encountered the error:
IdRegister.pas(215): E2225 Never-build package 'IndyProtocols230' must be recompiled.
I found that I was able to build and install dclIndyProtocols230.bpl if I removed the following from uses and RegisterComponents TIdDICT, TIdFTP, and TIdHTTPServer.
I followed up by running through removing and building it a few times. Using the package manager clean process and Lib\Clean_Seattle.cmd from the cmd prompt. Every time I get the error if those are included.
Any tips to building this or am I missing something?
For now, I don't think I need the missing units.

Are you sure you fully removed any lingering files of an older installation? Did you also remove the source files that ship with the IDE?

During the install, I chose to not install the feature, knowing I'd download the new version. I'll check to make sure it didn't copy the files anyway.
